# Удаление символов из начала и конца строки

Tags: python

Как убрать эти пробелы в начале и конце строки? Что это вообще за символы?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Отрыть то место, где эти пробелы написаны, и стереть их. При чём тут Python?

Comment: @andreymal это визуальный пример. В python мне нужно удалять эти пробелы при чтении строк из файла

Comment: Читаете файл в строку и обрабатываете эту строку любым нужным для вас способом. С чем возникли затруднения?

Comment: @andreymal сейчас доработаю вопрос

Comment: @andreymal вопрос дополнен

Comment: Выделяете курсором мыши мешающие вам пробелы и нажимаете Backspace, чтобы стереть их. Всё ещё непонятно, при чём тут Python и какие затруднения в питоне

Comment: @andreymal то что Вы сейчас описали нужно сделать на python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте при получении текста в теге `<a>` использоваться метод `replace(' ','')`.

Но также можно использовать метод `strip()` или `lstrip()` для удаления пробелов с двух сторон или только с левой части. Если там стоит `\n` справа, то можно использовать `rstrip('\n','')`

Comment: Тогда можно использовать string()

Comment: Вопрос дополнен

Comment: Виноват, не string(), а strip()